# Measuring 4-20mA with differential ADC

Tags: sensor, adc, 4-20ma

I have a question. Is it a good way to measuring 4-20mA with differential ADC?

Assume that we have a ADC with 2 single ended inputs or 1 differential input. Input A+ is the first input and input A- is the last input. If we connect a 4-20mA sensor to A+ and a resistor between A+ and GND so we get a pressure drop just to convert mA to Voltage.

Then on A- we do voltage dividing so we get the same input voltage as the sensor gives us at 4mA. Assume that we get 0.2V at 4mA from the sensor. When A+ and A- have 0.2V, then our ADC value is 0. When we have 20mA from the sensor, then our ADC shows maximum value.

Is this a good strategy?
Or should I use single ended ADC instead and accept that my ADC value will be a little bit higher because 4mA causes voltage input? So instead of the start ADC value will be 0, then we have e.g about 500 ADC value at start.

Comment: It all depends on the receiver, what power supplies it has and whether they are earthed and if isolation is required to prevent ground loops. It also depends on the specification of the 4/20 mA transmitter and (sometimes) it's power connections.

Comment: @Andyaka The sensor have 24V power supply. The GND have 0Voltage. So the best strategy is to have single ended ADC and measure 4-20mA with that? Not differential ADC?

Comment: All of my previous comment should be considered.

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry, can you elaborate that?

Comment: Take it one by one, I believe I was clear.

Comment: @Andyaka I did not understand.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson In order for it to work you want to connect the ground on the receiver with the ground on the transmitter.  Then use differential, not single ended.  And you need to ensure that the input range of the differential goes as high as the DC supply on the transmitter.

Comment: In case you want to go with your original idea of compensating for the 4mA caused voltage drop you might be able to just calibrate the differential ADC so that it shows 0 with 4mA (not the theorethical 500 or whatever). That way you could just hook up the A- to GND and avoid the voltage divider while still having 0 - MAX output range. Seems like too much of a hassle to me though.

Comment: @DanielAdamkovič Ok. So single ended is much preferred here and then accept that there is an initial ADC value at the start?